# Reference undescore in browserify and backbone set up

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js, browserify, lodash

I am trying to wrap my head around bundling an app as a node module using browserify and I have come across the following scenario:

```
var
  $ = require('jquery')(window),
  _ = require('underscore'),
  // _ = require('lodash/dist/lodash.underscore'),
  Backbone = require('backbone');

Backbone.$ = $;

var TodoView = new Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  tpl: _.template('An example template'),

  events: {/* dom events */},

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.tpl(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});

var todoView = new TodoView();

console.log(todoView.el); // => TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'
```

I can't seem to get a reference for the underscore function. I will definitely be needing it  to manipulate data. Templating is just an example use case here as there are other scalable [options](http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/01/browserify-sample-application-with-backbone-jquery-handlebars-and-cordova/).

On the same note, I have also tried to reference `lodash.underscore` to no success and it gives same error.

I have hunch I am missing something here. Any help?

Comment: The problem isn't with underscore or lodash. First, you put a `new` operator before `Backbone.View.extend` call which is a wrong way to define a subclass. Second, you don't have to do `require('jquery')(window)` but rather just `require('jquery')`.

Comment: Also you can do `browserify --debug` and see the lines where the code throws an exception — that way it's much easier to debug such errors.